# Vb.net - Filtering data tables with multiple columns

Tags: vb.net

Just started working with datatable, it has 21 columns(only 3 to 4 are needed to sort),and 67000+ lines.
So what I wanted to know was how to search for rows with those column then save it to another table.

:/ been at it 3weeks can't get past loading it to table. ..
Wanting to find which rows are both 0 and type2.

X - TYPE - QTY.
‐-------------.
1 - type1 - 1.
1 - type2 - 0.
1 - type1 - 0.
1 - type1 - 1.
1 - type2 - 0.

I've used a for loop with a if statement trying to match the desired rows to then move desire rows for each line to new table.:/ so far stuck on sorting through part. Only working code is in a old vba project ment for excel.

Comment: More info needed.  What is this datatable, what are the columns.  What have you tied and how did it not meet expectations?

Comment: Updated, mostly used for loops and if statements.

Comment: Have you considered using a Linq query to select your desired records? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a populated `DataTable` that can't be changed using the original query, you can use a `DataView` to sort and filter the data. You can't easily affect the data exposed via the `Rows` collection, but the `DefaultView` property is type `DataView`, which has `Sort` and `RowFilter` properties.

You mention sorting in your question but I suspect that that's a mistake and all you actually want is filtering. You can set the `RowFilter` to filter the data exposed via the `DefaultView`. You can then just access the data via that `DataView`, or you can call `ToTable` to generate a new `DataTable` based on that sort and filter, e.g.

```vb
oldTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Type = 'type2' AND Qty = 0"

Dim newTable = oldTable.DefaultView.ToTable()
```

Note that, when you bind a `DataTable` in WinForms, it is the `DefaultView` that the bound data is pulled from. If you don't want to filter the `DefaultView` of the table, e.g. you don't want to affect bound controls, then you can explicitly create a new `DataView` and use that.

Comment: Got an error "syntax error : missing operand after 'type' operator. "

Comment: Never-ending error was todo with the column title having a space. Adding [] around the title fixed that. But now can't use the table visualizer to check if its been filtered.